# PHP API: Rollback behavior with multible Querys

Tags: rollback

My system imports large tables into salesforce. I want the all or nothing behavior, specified [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_allornoneheader.htm)

But i can't find the corresponding function in the php SDK.

- Does this functionality exists in the PHP SDK?
- Does this behavior work, if I need to roll back multiple requests?
- What would be best practice to implement a roll back in salesforce language independend?
- If there is no PHP realisation, how would you implement this behavior within salesforce? Are there additional querys, functions, API Calls etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AllOrNone behavior applies *per transaction,* which is strictly defined as a single API call. In practice, this means that every 200 or so records of a single type will become a single transaction. You can't specify things like "autocommit=0" or "start transaction/rollback/commit" in that sense, because salesforce.com doesn't give us that level of granularity over our transactions. The AllOrNone header applies simply to a *single batch of records (up to 200)*, where *true*, the default, means any failure causes all rows to rollback, and *false* allows just the rows that fail to rollback. Complex transaction logic needs to be handled by way of a custom REST or SOAP function written in Apex Code, but this will only allow an effect of up to 10,000 rows; you still must choose to commit or rollback by the time this limit is reached. This is in stark contrast to systems that allow transactions of arbitrary size (perhaps even millions of records) without explicitly committing.

Therefore, all of the answers to your questions are essentially "No," "No," "N/A (because you can't)," and "N/A (because you can't)."

Comment: Even if it is not what i wanted to hear, it answers the question. Thank you.